# Imacros Javascript Macro Random Variable Question

Tags: javascript, firefox, var, imacros

I created a script to run on imacros to update the resolution of responsive design mode on firefox but after the script choice random value do not extract the correct value of array.

Can you help me to solve, i need to add the result of random array.

This is the code

```
myheight = new Array();
myheight.push("1000");
myheight.push("1100");
myheight.push("1200");

randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*myheight.length);
iimSet("height",myheight[randomint]);

mywidth = new Array();
mywidth.push("800");
mywidth.push("900");
mywidth.push("1000");

randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*mywidth.length);
iimSet("width",mywidth[randomint]);


var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
prefs.setCharPref("devtools.responsiveUI.customHeight", "height");
prefs.setCharPref("devtools.responsiveUI.customWidth", "width");
```

[image]

This script must update the values extracted but do not extract correctly the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following script should work:

```
myheight = new Array();
myheight.push("1000");
myheight.push("1100");
myheight.push("1200");

randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*myheight.length);
height = myheight[randomint];

mywidth = new Array();
mywidth.push("800");
mywidth.push("900");
mywidth.push("1000");

randomint = Math.floor(Math.random()*mywidth.length);
width = mywidth[randomint];

var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
prefs.setCharPref("devtools.responsiveUI.customHeight", height);
prefs.setCharPref("devtools.responsiveUI.customWidth", width);
```

The `iimSet()` function is useless without the `iimPlayCode()` (or `iimPlay()`) functions called later in the code.